# Retrieving Data from Local Storage - key value pairs apparently don't match (error)

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid

I am trying to make a functional login and registration pages (I know that in real life I need to store the login info in a database but for now I would like to see my pages "working"). I created two pages with forms one for registration and one for login. I also have two JS files one for locally storing input values (registerDetails.js) and one for retrieving those values during login (login.js).

Storing the information is not a problem, however, when I try to log in with the information I have just inputted and know it's correct it still throws an "Error" at me to say that password and username don't match even though I know they do match.

SOLUTION IN THE COMMENTS - MIX UP OF VARIABLES

I even tried to error handle if there is a problem with browser compatibility, still to no avail.
This is HTML for register.html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <fieldset>
    <div id="legend">
      <legend>
        Register or <a class="login-link" href="login.html">Login</a>
      </legend>
      <p>All fileds marked with * are required.</p>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div class="control-group">
      <!-- Username -->
      <label class="control-label" for="username"><span class="asterisk">*</span> Username</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Any letters or numbers without spaces"
          class="input-xlarge" />
      </div>
      <br />
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <!-- E-mail -->
      <label class="control-label" for="email"><span class="asterisk">*</span> E-mail</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email here" class="input-xlarge" />
      </div>
      <br />
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <!-- Password-->
      <label class="control-label" for="password"><span class="asterisk">*</span> Password</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password of atleast 4 characters"
          class="input-xlarge" />
      </div>
      <br />
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <!-- Password -->
      <label class="control-label" for="password_confirm"><span class="asterisk">*</span> Confirm Password</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="password" id="password_confirm" name="password_confirm" placeholder="Please confirm password"
          class="input-xlarge" />
      </div>
      <br />
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
      <!-- Button -->
      <div class="controls">
        <button type="submit" id="register" class="btn btn-success" onClick="store()">
          Register
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here is my HTML for login.html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <div id="legend">
        <legend>
          Login or <a class="login-link" href="register.html">Register</a>
        </legend>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div class="control-group">
        <!-- Username or Email-->
        <label class="control-label" for="username">Username or Email</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" id="usernameEmail" name="usernameEmail" placeholder="Enter your email or username"
            class="input-xlarge" />
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <!-- Password-->
        <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="password" id="passwordLogin" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password"
            class="input-xlarge" />
        </div>
        <br />
      </div>

      <div class="control-group">
        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="controls">
          <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" onclick="check()">Login</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
```

My registration JS works fine, the browser prompts me to save credentials for later use...
Which is here:

```
// Getting details from the registration form to later store their values

var userName = document.getElementById('username');
var userEmail = document.getElementById('email');
var password = document.getElementById('password');
var passwordConfirm = document.getElementById('password_confirm');

// Locally storing input value from register-form
function store() {
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem('name', userName.value);
        localStorage.setItem('email', userEmail.value);
        localStorage.setItem('password', password.value);
        localStorage.setItem('password_confirmation', passwordConfirm.value);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
    }
}
```

My login page, however, throws the ERROR alert, even when I know for sure that the username and password match.

```
// check if stored data from register-form is equal to entered data in the login-form
function check() {

// stored data from the register-form
var storedName = localStorage.getItem('name');
// var storedEmail = localStorage.getItem('email');
var storedPassword = localStorage.getItem('password');


// entered data from the login-form
var userNameLogin = document.getElementById('usernameEmail');
var userPwLogin = document.getElementById('passwordLogin');

// check if stored data from register-form is equal to data from login form

if (userNameLogin.value == storedName && storedPassword.value == userPwLogin) {
    alert('You are loged in.');
} else {
    alert('ERROR.');
}
```

}

I have spent a few hours trying to rewrite the code to maybe see some typos or mistakes but I cannot find where I am going wrong! If anyone could help out as to show the reason why it does not match the username and password would be great.

It should alert me "You are logged in."

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo

```js
if (userNameLogin.value == storedName && storedPassword.value == userPwLogin) {
                                         ^^Here
}
```

Should be this instead

```js
if (userNameLogin.value == storedName && userPwLogin.value == storedPassword ) {

}
```

By the way, your code will only log in with username (and not email) as it is. Don't forget to compare the email too.

Comment: Wow. So all I had to do was switch the two around. Thank you for your help! And yes I will compare those too just wanted to get the main parts working without getting mixed up in the code, I guess that didn't help :)

Answer (score 0):

Variables that are meant to store your elements at register page(userName, userEmail, etc.) might be null when store() is called.
I would suggest to get those inside the function:

```
function store() {
    var userName = document.getElementById('username');
    var userEmail = document.getElementById('email');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var passwordConfirm = document.getElementById('password_confirm');
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem('name', userName.value);
        localStorage.setItem('email', userEmail.value);
        localStorage.setItem('password', password.value);
        localStorage.setItem('password_confirmation', passwordConfirm.value);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
    }
}
```

But the solution lies in this line:

```
if (userNameLogin.value == storedName && storedPassword.value == userPwLogin)
```

In your case storedPassword doesn't have "value" and userPwLogin does, since userPwLogin is the element on your form

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working right because you've mixed up your local storage variable with your input elements. This line:

```
if (userNameLogin.value === storedName && storedPassword.value === userPwLogin) {
```

it should be:

```
if (userNameLogin.value === storedName && userPwLogin.value === storedPassword) {
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.